# Get the folder name with the freshest modification date

Tags: php, directory

I want to get the newest folder name from my localization.

At the moment I have a variable:

```
$videoFolder = '../camera/cam3/VideoEvent_201910241906/';
```

Unfortunately, my camera from time to time create a new folder with other name (for example: VideoEvent_201910241906). I use this to displaying video from this folder on my page, so I need to see always the files from newest folder.

Do you know how I can get the name of the newest folder (folder with the freshest modification date) to display his name as in the example in my variable?

The best option will be a variable (for example with name $videoEvent) who give me the name of folder this to the variable:

```
$videoFolder = '../camera/cam3/' . $videoEvent . '/';
```

If something is incomprehensible, please ask questions :)

Comment: Read all folder names into an array, and then sort that array by the date portion extracted from the file name … oh, and, of course - _If something is incomprehensible, please ask questions :)_ (I’m being a bit sarcastic here, because your question so far doesn’t show any real effort on your part - which it should, please go see [ask].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it alone. For other people who want the correct answer, information below.

I created a variable:

```
$videoEvent = scandir('../camera/cam3/', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
```

and edited my previous variable to:

```
$videoFolder = '../camera/cam3/' . $videoEvent[0] . '/';
```

This works great :)